# clone files in bitbucket using http

Tags: git, netbeans, windows-10, ssh-keys, bitbucket-server

I have cloned files using ssh in bitbucket until now and have no issues. For some reason, I need to clone files from bitbucket into NetBean using http. I simply switch ssh to http in bitbucket. However, I got the following error:

"Cannot connect to repository at https://bitbucket ..."

Does anybody have similar experience? Is there a way to fix the problem?

Secondly, I also tried SSH method in NetBean. However, I couldn't make the certificate portion work. Is there a way to disable this certificate check in NetBean using command: git config --global http.sslVerify false?

The OS I am using is Windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is [no  incident on BitBucket side](https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/), make sure your HTTPS URL is a bitbucket.org one (assuming you are using BitBucket Cloud)

If you have [activated 2FA](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/two-step-verification-777023203.html) (two-factor authentication), HTTPS access would not be possible directly.

If not, check your `git config credential.helper`, to see if the wrong account/password has been cached.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your URL is misconfigured.  First, Bitbucket uses HTTPS, not plain HTTP, so you need to use `https` instead of `http`.  Secondly, you've used a backslash (`\`), which is not allowed in URLs.  You must use a forward slash (`/`) instead.

There may be additional issues, but without seeing the entire error message including the full URL, we wouldn't be able to say.

Comment: It is my typo as modified above. Sorry

Comment: As mentioned, you'll need to place the entire error message, as text, in the body of your comment.  Usually there is additional information in the error message that will be helpful, telling us specifically why the connection failed.